# RegEx troubles with converting text to links

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to make my shoutbox automatically convert posted data into links if it matches certain criteria. It works, except not if there is more than one link in a single shoutbox post.

Here is my code that is meant to convert it:

```
<?
            $text = "edit:4961310112967 - edit:021331612649 Are these correct?";
            echo $text."<br><br>";
            $view = "/(view|edit)\:[0-9]+(\S)?/";
            if(preg_match_all($view, $text, $url, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {

                    foreach ($url as $val) {
                        echo "(matched: " . $val[0] . ")\n";
                        $checkCode = explode(":", $val[0]);
                        if(strcmp($checkCode[0], 'view') == 0) {
                            $text = preg_replace($view, '<a target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline;color:purple;font-weight:bold;" href="../index.php?UPC='.$checkCode[1].'">(View Product)</a>', $text);
                        } else if(strcmp($checkCode[0], 'edit') == 0) {
                            $text = preg_replace($view, '<a target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline;color:purple;font-weight:bold;" href="../edit.php?UPC='.$checkCode[1].'">(Edit Product)</a>', $text);
                        }
                        echo "<br>".$text;
                        echo "<br>(".$checkCode[0]." - ".$checkCode[1].")<br><br>";

                    }

            }
            echo "<br><br>".$text."<br><br>"; ?>
```

As you can see, the $text variable at the top has 2 spots where it says "edit:" - that is what is meant to call the regex to turn it into a link. The link in question would be, for example,

```
<a href="edit.php?UPC=############"</a>
```

Currently, how it is, when there is more than one call to the regex, it basically makes both links the first edit:

Sorry, I don't feel like I am explaining this very well.

this string: edit:4961310112967 - edit:021331612649 Are these correct?
the regex would make both links edit.php?UPC=4961310112967

Comment: Your approach is wrong because all has been already replaced in the first pass of the foreach loop (so with the first result datas) since `preg_replace` makes a global replacement (all occurrences of the string). your pattern seems good except you need to add a capture group to avoid to use `explode` later. A more simple way here is to use `preg_replace_callback`. `preg_match_all`, `preg_replace` and a `foreach` loop are not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably simplify it a bit by dividing it in to 2 regular expressions.

https://regex101.com/r/bN9qY5/2

```
$re = "/edit\\:([0-9]+(\\S)?)/m"; 
$str = "edit:4961310112967 - edit:021331612649 Are these correct?\n\nedit:1231289389123\n\nedit:123123lkajsdad\n\nview:234234234234234"; 
$subst = "<a href=\"edit.php?UPC=$1\"</a>"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

and then do the same for view.
Hope it helps!

Comment: @Timothy Lee  for this  case: `edit:123123kajsdad`  it wrong match as UPC= `123123k`

Answer (score 1):

A way that avoids to parse the string several times:

```
$text = "edit:4961310112967 - edit:021331612649 Are these correct?";

$pattern = '~\b(edit|view):(\d+)~Si';

$links = [
    'edit' => ['className' => 'editLink', 'URL' => '../edit.php', 'txt' => '(Edit Product)'],
    'view' => ['className' => 'viewLink', 'URL' => '../index.php', 'txt' => '(view Product)']
];

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) use ($links) {
    $action = strtolower($m[1]);
    return '<a class="' . $links[$action]['className']
         . '" href="' . $links[$action]['URL'] . '?UPC=' . $m[2]
         . '">' . $links[$action]['txt'] . '</a>';
}, $text);
```

You need to define the two classes `editLink` and `viewLink` in your css file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not want tot use `preg_replace` for the string generation, I believe that is mostly the issue at hand.  See this example on using `sprintf` that should behave correctly.

http://ideone.com/FrfsEN

Answer (score 0):

**Do you want to following this?**

**regex** : `(edit|view)\:([0-9]+)`

```
$re = "/(edit|view)\\:([0-9]+)/m"; 
$str = "edit:4961310112967 - edit:021331612649 Are these correct?\n\nedit:1231289389123\n\nedit:123123lkajsdad\n\nview:234234234234234"; 
$subst = "<a href=\"$1.php?UPC=$2\">($1 Product)</a>"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bN9qY5/4)**